# Load a page with AJAX in VSTS extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I am trying to write a VSTS extension. I am running in some troubles when I try to create a menu in a hub page.

**Current state:**
I have a VSTS extension where I create a hub like Home or Work. In this Hub I load the page index.html. In this page I have two divs a menu div and a content div.

```
 <div id="menuDiv" class="menuDiv"></div>
 <div class="rightPane">
     <div id="contentDiv" class="content"> </div>
 </div>
```

**What I want:**
When I click on a menu button I want to load a page with Ajax.

I tryed the following code:

```
    $("#contentDiv").load("../pages/test.html", function () {
    });
```

**The Problem:**
When I click on a link. I get a HTTP403 error (The request has been read from the server but is forbidden). And if I have a look on the server response I see the following errors:

**Descriptor**: "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.UnauthenticatedIdentity;S-1-0-0"

**Message**: Access Denied: Anonymous access is not allowed on the resource // for action: Read details about an existing publisher or extension

**typeName**: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Security.AccessCheckException, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi

**typeKey**: AccessCheckException

**Ideas:**
I see that there is an authentification problem. But I don't understand why. The pages are running on the same server. 
Is there maybe an additional method or workaround? Or how can I fix that? I am pretty sure that using an iframe will not solve the problem.

Note: The extension is running on VSTS so it runs on a https page.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this one?  I'm getting a very similar error.